# R batch all files in folder

Tags: r, batch-file, directory

I have a list of `.R` files such as `UK.R`, `France.R`, `Peru.R`, `Australia.R`, and so on, in a folder called `script_countries`.

Instead of doing each file separately

```
R CMD BATCH UK.R output.txt
```

I was wondering if I could launch all the `Rscripts` with `R CMD BATCH`.

In other words, *how can I `R CMD BATCH` all files in a directory?*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about R, but a `FOR` loop should work:

```bat
CD "C:\adjust\path"
FOR %%G IN ("*.R") DO (R CMD BATCH %%~nxG output.txt)
```

If you want mutliple output files you could replace `output.txt` with `output_%%~nG.txt` or something similar.

If your files contain spaces you might want to add quotation marks around the input and output, but I don't know how R handles that.